# signup for mvnrepository.com and upload a jar

Tags: java, maven, artifact

I'm new to this, trying to upload a library to mvnrepository.com. It's a bit confusing for me, for instance I'm not seeing any link to register an account there, so I could upload the jar file.

I'm also thrown off by sonatype and nexus and it has confused me more on where to go.

I read this [article](http://www.apache.org/dev/publishing-maven-artifacts.html#signing-up) but where do I sign up to begin with?

Comment: Do you want to publish an open-source library to the Maven central repository? Because mvnrepository is just a web site listing the projects published there (and in some other public repositories).

Comment: yes, it's an open source library

Comment: See https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html.

Comment: I see, I'll go through it, just for info can you change group id and artifact id of an existing library or delete/re-create it?

Comment: No. Once published, it's published.

Comment: ok, I understand groupId is reverse domain style but can you append some related info to it. for instance `org.mydomain.util` and artifactId `StateMachine`?